# wrap multi-line comments in vs code

Tags: comments, visual-studio-code

VS Code seems to understand what it means to wrap multi-line comments differently from what other IDEs understand. For instance if I set Intellij to wrap multi-line comments at column 100, it breaks the line for me. But if I ask VS Code to do the same, it visually wraps the line but if I later open the same file in a simple text editor, I get one long line.

How do I get VS Code to auto break long comment lines?

Intellij:

```
/**
* Intellij will break this line
* at the correct location 
* because I asked it to break 
*/
```

VS Code

```
/**
* VS Code will wrap this line
 at the correct location 
 but it's really one very 
 long line. 
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think VS Code provides native support for this.

There is an extension in the marketplace for this though: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap.